# SSRS Tablix duplicating first and last item in PDF export

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, duplicates, ssrs-2012

Here is my setup

1. I have a SSRS report that is deployed to a server.
2. The report has a tablix that is generated from the dataset embedded in the report.
3. It is using a single dataset to pull all the information that is in the report.
4. The dataset is a stored procedure from a database on the same server as the reports hosted environment.
5. The data source is a shared data source among other reports.

Here is my problem

When accessing the report from outside of the server on another server or machine on the same network as an exported PDF using URL Access parameters, If the report has 20 rows of data in the tablix the very first and very last rows are duplicates on the initial load. The very last row is the duplicate, it repeats the very first row in place of the actual last row from the dataset. When using Chrome or IE the first time the report is called I get the duplicate values, every call after this until a "clean session" is called I will receive the correct and complete list of values. If I wait long enough or specify the "ClearSession=True" in the url then the duplicate values will appear. The problem can be repeated constantly by including "ClearSession=True" in the url.

Testing / Troubleshooting

1. Testing the stored procedure that is used by the dataset has shown no errors
2. The same dataset is used by another element (a 2d barcode in image format) that provides all the values in the list correctly.
3. Testing the report in preview on the server has shown no errors
4. Testing the report with regular rendering on the server has shown no errors.
5. Testing the report with regular rendering outside of the hosted server has shown no errors.
6. Testing the report by exporting to Excel has shown no errors (even in the same circumstances as PDF).
7. Using a GUID on the "View=" paired with and without the ClearSession=True in the URL Access parameters did not change anything.
8. I am unable to perform an export from the deployed report directly on the server due to restrictions to downloading content (provided by another dept in the company I work for)

Observations

1. Even though caching has been disabled, the @ExecutionTime parameter on the report in the footer does not refresh/update with consecutive calls to generate a PDF. The only way I can get it to refresh is to wait for it to do so on its own after the session has cleared or to specify ClearSession=True in the URL, which causes the duplicating problem to persist every time.
2. It appears as if the PDF exporting functionality embedded in the report is not rendering the data correctly on first load.

Thanks in advance for any help provided, I will try my best to answer questions as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting the Tablix row height fixed the issue. After increasing the row height slightly, it made the report generate less rows on the first page and more on the remaining page(s). Before there were 10 rows on each page. Now that the row height has been increased there are 9 on the first and 11 on the second. I have tested to make sure that it wouldn't happen after the changes by displaying reports that have 8 items on the first and second page. It was successful.

Note - There were no warnings coming from the compiler about overlapping elements, so there was no way for me to know if this was an issue, but I did end up moving elements to make room for the increased row height.

Additional Information - Since I posted this I continued troubleshooting the issue, we have production and development environments setup for each client. This specific issue was happening on both production and development, which are on the same server. Deploying the report in a different environment showed no problems. This may have been a problem with the version of studio I was using with specific environment variables on the server.